# DataWeave: Transformation of huge payload takes alot of time

Tags: dataweave, mule4

The input to the the mule 4 api comes from a Stored Procedure. It consists of about 5k records with almost 120 fields (most of them are arrays). These fields are to be validated and transformation of the records is done in a json format with a structure which is different than the input structure.

This transformation takes around 2 mins to parse the data when deployed on a local machine (and literally dies if this resource is requested when deployed on cloudhub). Is there any way that it can be broken into pieces and multi threading can be used around it? Or anything that can be done to reduce the processing time.

I am also using some custom functions to validate the date and time format for avoiding code repetition.
The stored procedure supposed to touched as it is developed by some other vendor.

PS: FYI, if the array fields from 5K records are seperated then it converts 5K records to around 200k records.(Each array field is a table in itself)

Comment: The question is too abstract. Which version of Mule Runtime, which version of the database connector? Please also share table structure, XML for the flow (in text format) including query and transformations and database configuration. What is the worker size you tried in CloudHub? How long does it take to perform the database query? What are the custom functions?

Comment: To have an idea of the memory footprint, if you just call the DB, transform it to JSON as it is and store that into a file, how big that file is?

Comment: We also don't know how you're doing the transformation/validation. I've seen dataweave transformations that would take 18 seconds to run on a payload, but after fixing the code so they weren't iterating the entire data set `2^N` times for no reason, it was running fast enough that the API calls were taking <50ms, meaning network latency is now the bottleneck. You will need to provide more complete information on what you are doing and how you are doing it.

Comment: @Satyam Pisal, Just a thought-> May be you can try offloading some of your transformations in dataweave to the stored proc and see to what extent it helps. I faced a similar issue earlier , and using this approach helped a lot.